# list files or dirs starting with 'jre'

Tags: command-line, filesystem, ls, posix-compliant

I need to list files and dirs with names starting with `jre` (small and capital letters are allowed).

When I execute:

```
ls | grep jre
```

...it greps just low capital letters and gives output with `jre` not only in start position. Actually I have feeling that grep is not a good choice at all in this case.

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find`. In your case you can run

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname 'jre*'
```

Explanation:

`find` searches for files/directories with the given parameters: `-maxdepth 1` restricts the search to the current directory. Otherwise, it would search in all subdirectories too. `-iname` takes the pattern and searches case insensitive. The pattern itself `'jre*'` means the string should begin with "jre" and the continue with a arbitrary number of cahracters.

Alternatively, if you want to use `grep`:

```
ls | grep -i '^jre'
```

`-i` toggles case-insensitive search and the `^` results in finding only matches with "jre" at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Find should do the trick:

```
find . -iname 'jre*'
```